# How to collapse all the childviews above and below of a groupview in expandablelistview?

Tags: android, android-studio, expandablelistview, android-contacts

I am trying to create a contactlist app..i took an expandable listview,with a layout as a childview for each group(contact). when i click on the contact(groupView),the child will expand(layout).now when i click on another contact, i want the previous expanded groups to be collapsed..can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the current expanded group position stored in a variable. In **onGroupExpanded** do the following. **lastExpandedPosition** contains the recently expanded child

```
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
private ExpandableListView lv; //your expandable listview
...

lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                lv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```